Google Drive APIを利用したフォルダー作成がうまくいかない
Google Drive APIを利用したフォルダー作成についてお教え下さい。
JavaからGoogle Drive APIを利用して、Google Drive上の共有フォルダーに新しいフォルダーを作ろうとしており、GCPにプロジェクトを作成し試験をしていますが、上手くいきません。
方法として、以下の手順です。

リフレッシュトークンを取得。
この手順の中で、認証コードを取得する時に利用したユーザIDは開発者のIDです。
開発者のIDで目的の共有ドライブにフォルダーやファイルを作成する事は可能です。
Javaプログラムの中で、以下の順序で処理をしています。

取得したリフレッシュトークンとGoogle Drive APIを利用してアクセストークンを取得。

取得したアクセストークンを利用して、Google Drive APIを呼び出します。
順番としては、

操作対象の共有ドライブID(事前に取得)を指定してしてフォルダーの一覧を取得。
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
レスポンスでフォルダー一覧を取得し、対象のフォルダーのIDを取得。

取得した対象フォルダーのIDを親フォルダーとして、フォルダーを作成
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
この時、指定した親フォルダーのIDが無いとエラーになります。
フォルダー一覧取得ではアクセスできたのに、フォルダー作成の親フォルダーに指定すると、アクセス不能になってしまいます。
アクセストークンのレスポンスでは、
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
となっており、アクセス権は有る様に見えます。
Javaのコードが悪いのか、Googleの設定が悪いのか判断つきかねております。
確認ポイントでも良いのでご指導頂けると助かります。


以下にエラーメッセージを示します。
  statusCode=404
  response=(POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/) 404
  responseBody={
    "error": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "File not found: xxxxxx(指定したファイルIDxxxxxxR0.",
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "File not found: xxxxxx(指定したファイルIDxxxxxxR0.",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "notFound",
          "location": "fileId",
          "locationType": "parameter"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

この部分のコードは以下です。
    /**
     * フォルダーを作成する
     * parentFolderID:前段で取得した親になるフォルダー
     * targetFolderName：新規に作成するフォルダー名
     */
    private  String  makeFolder( String parentFolderID, String targetFolderName ){
        
        //POSTデータの生成
        HttpResponse<String>    response        =    null;
        String                  responseBody    =    "";
        List<String>tempParentFolderID;
        tempParentFolderID    =    new ArrayList<String>();
        tempParentFolderID.add( parentFolderID );
        
        Map<String, Object> postParmMap = new HashMap<>();
        postParmMap.put("name", targetFolderName);                              //フォルダー名
        postParmMap.put("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" );     //mimeType
        postParmMap.put("driveId", DRIVE_ID );                                  //共有ドライブのID
        postParmMap.put("teamDriveId", DRIVE_ID );                              //共有ドライブのID
        postParmMap.put("parents",  tempParentFolderID );                       //親フォルダーID
        postParmMap.put("corpora",  "drive" );
        postParmMap.put("useDomainAdminAccess", true);                          //共有ドライブをサポートする
        postParmMap.put("supportsAllDrives", true);                             //共有ドライブをサポートする
        postParmMap.put("includeItemsFromAllDrives", true);                     //共有ドライブをサポートする
        System.out.println( "postParmMap=" + postParmMap );
        
        // POST送信
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create( ENDPOINT ))    //https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken )
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(new Gson().toJson(postParmMap)))
                .build();
            response        =    httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            responseBody    =    response.body();
        
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("エラー\n"+e.getMessage());
                System.exit(40);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("エラー\n"+e.getMessage());
                System.exit(30);
        }
        int    statusCode    =   response.statusCode();
    
        System.out.println( "statusCode=" + statusCode );
        System.out.println( "response=" + response );
        System.out.println( "responseBody=" + responseBody );
        
        //レスポンスが正常なら
        if ( statusCode == 200) {
            System.out.println( "作成成功" );
        }  else  {
            System.out.println( "作成失敗" );
        }
        return        "";
    }

取得したアクセストークンは以下となっております。
AccessTpkenのresponseBody={
  "access_token": "ya(中略)71",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}


hiromasa masuda様
ご回答を頂き大変ありがとうございます。
さて早速ご指導頂いた通りに4つのプロパティーを設定してみました。
        Map<String, Object> postParmMap = new HashMap<>();
        postParmMap.put("kind", "drive#file" );                                    //Kind
        postParmMap.put("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" );        //mimeType
        postParmMap.put("name", targetFolderName);                                 //フォルダー名
        postParmMap.put("parents",  tempParentFolderID );                          //親フォルダーID
//1        postParmMap.put("corpora",  "allDrives" );
//2        postParmMap.put("useDomainAdminAccess", true);                          //共有ドライブをサポートする
//3        postParmMap.put("supportsAllDrives", true);                             //共有ドライブをサポートする

以下がPOSTする前のGSONの内容です。
postParmMap
{
  "kind":"drive#file",
  "name":"TestFolder01",
  "mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
  "parents":["親共有フォルダーのID"]
}

ところが、"File not found: 親共有フォルダーのID."となってしまい、私の環境では上手く動きません。
親共有フォルダーのIDの最後に「.」が付いていますが、これは問題無いのでしょうか？
その前段で取得した親共有フォルダーの情報(REST Resource: files)を見ると一例ですが、以下となっています。
capabilities.canEdit: true,
capabilities.canRename: true,
capabilities.canAddChildren: true,
capabilities.canDeleteChildren: false,

「canDeleteChildren」がfalseなのが気になりますが「canAddChildren」はtrue
ですし、「canEdit」もtrueなので、更新のアクセス権は有している様に見えます。
これ以外にもソースコードの//1～//３を付けたり消したりしてみましたが、同様の
結果です。
以下のエラーとなった時のレスポンスを示します。
responseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: 共有フォルダーのID.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "File not found: 共有フォルダーのID.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "location": "fileId",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

============================================================
H Sasaki様
ご回答を頂き大変ありがとうございます。
まず、フォルダーIDの最後の「.」は問題無い旨ありがとうございました。
次に、ご指導に従い、親フォルダーに共有ドライブID(即ちRoot)を
指定しました。
フォルダーを作成するメソッドを改め、共有ドライブIDを直接指定しました。
makeFolder( "共有ドライブID", "TestFolder01" );

結果は、
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "File not found: 共有ドライブID.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "location": "fileId",
    "locationType": "parameter"
  }

となり、同様のエラーになってしまいます。
因みに
ドライブ指定をMyDriveにしておいて
private static final String DRIVE_ID    = "MyDriveのID";    //MyDrive

以下の様にMyDrive直下に「試験フォルダー」フォルダーを作成しようとすると
成功します。
makeFolder( "MyDriveのID", "試験フォルダー" );    //MyDrive

statusCode=200
response=(POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files) 200
responseBody={
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "フォルダーID",
  "name": "試験フォルダー",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}

=================================================================
hiromasa masuda様、H Sasaki様
纏めての回答で失礼致します。
hiromasa masuda様
親フォルダーIDの確認について、確認しましたが正しい様です。
H Sasaki様
アクセストークンはOAuthを利用しています。
手順としては以下の流れです。
1.GCPプロジェクトの作成
GCPプロジェクト自体は弊社内部で管理している部門に依頼しての作成です。
2.APIの設定
APIとサービスから、有効なAPIとサービスを表示
ここでGoogleDriveAPIを有効化しました。
OAutt同意画面に移動
アプリ名等を設定
スコープの指定で、以下を指定
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
3.認証情報の設定
OauthクライアントIDを選択
アプリケーション種類は、ウェブアプリケーションを選択
JSONをダウンロード
4.RefreshTokenの取得
クライアントIDやリダイレクトURLを利用して呼び出しURLを作成
ユーザIDを入力して認証
この時示されたアクセス権が以下
「Google ドライブのすべてのファイルの表示、編集、作成、削除」
返ってきた結果よりcode=以下を取得
GASを利用してRefreshTokenを取得
5.Javaプログラムの設定
1.Javaの中で、先に取得したRefreshTokenを利用してAccessTokenを取得
2.AccessToken、事前に確保しておいたドライブIDを利用してフォルダーを検索
3.取得したフォルダーIDを指定し、そのフォルダー内にフォルダーを
作成しようとすると親フォルダーIDNotFoundでエラーになります。
ここで、H Sasaki様の仰る様に、ドライブIDをMyDriveにすると
フォルダーは作成されます。(リターンコード200)

と言うのが今までのあらましです。
Javaプログラムの問題では無く、GoogleDriveの設定の問題だとした場合、
確認のポイントの様なものはございますでしょうか？
===============================================================
hiromasa masuda様
ありがとうございます。
OAuth 認証しているユーザー(自分のID)で、ブラウザーからログインして、
UI 操作で、共有フォルダー以下にフォルダーを作成してみました。
ブラウザーからGoogleDriveのルート直下にフォルダーを作成すると作成できます。
今、作成したフォルダー名を指定し、フォルダー内に新しいフォルダーを作ろうと
すると、「"message": "File not found: 指定したファイルID.",」となって
しまいます。
エラーメッセージのファイルIDと、ブラウザーから作成したフォルダーのIDは
同じです。
その前段で、フォルダーの一覧を取得しています。
ここでは、作成したフォルダー名を指定し、対象のフォルダー情報を読み取って
います。
"id": "今作成したフォルダーのID",
"name": "試験フォルダー２",
ファイルの一覧は取得できるので、認証エラーになるのは不思議です。
対象のフォルダーは一覧を取得できるのに、子のフォルダーを作成
しようとすると読めなく(書けなく)なるのが不思議です。
AccessTpkenの中でもscopeは以下を示しています。
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
フォルダー情報取得のソースを以下に示します。
    /**
 * フォルダーの一覧を取得する
 */
private  List<File>  getFolderList( String parentFolderID, String targetFolderName ){

    List<File>    folderList =   new ArrayList<File>();    //フォルダー一覧
    String                pageToken    =    null;          //PageToken
    Gson    gson    =    new  Gson();
    
    String  qStr    =    "";
    qStr        =  qStr         + "mimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\'";
    qStr        =  qStr         + " and trashed=false";
    qStr        =  qStr         + " and \'" + parentFolderID + "\'" + " in parents";
    qStr        =  qStr         + " and name contains \'" + targetFolderName + "\'";
    System.out.println( "qStr=" + qStr );

    //ＨＴＴＰリクエスト部分
    do{
        String  endpoint    =    ""; 
        try {
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  ENDPOINT;
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "?corpora=drive";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&driveId=" + DRIVE_ID;
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&useDomainAdminAccess=true";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&supportsAllDrives=true";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&fields=nextPageToken,kind,";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "files(";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +    "kind,driveId,fileExtension,";
            省略
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  ")";
            endpoint    =  endpoint  +  "&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(qStr, "UTF-8");
            if (pageToken != null) {
                endpoint      =  endpoint  + "&pageToken=" + URLEncoder.encode(pageToken, "UTF-8");
            }

            //GET送信
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build();

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create( endpoint ))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .GET()
                .build();
        
            System.out.println( "request=" + request );
        
            HttpResponse<String> response    =    httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            String    responseBody           =    response.body();
            int        statusCode            =    response.statusCode();
        
            System.out.println( "statusCode=" + statusCode );
            System.out.println( "response=" + response );
            System.out.println( "responseBody=" + responseBody );
            
            //レスポンスが正常なら
            if ( statusCode == 200) {

                //レスポンスをパースする
                   FoledrList    foledrList     =     gson.fromJson(responseBody, FoledrList.class);
                   
                //クラスの中を読みだす
                //FolderItemオブジェクトの抽出
                for( File elm : foledrList.files ){
                    //フォルダー情報を追加する
                    folderList.add( elm );
                }
                   // nextPageTokenを更新
                   pageToken    =    foledrList.nextPageToken;
                
            }  else  {
                System.out.println("Google Drive API Response Status:"  + response.statusCode());
                System.out.println("Google Drive API Response Body:"    + response.body());
                pageToken    =    null;
            }
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }             
         
    } while (pageToken != null);    //nextPageTokenが設定されているうちは繰り返す
    return        folderList;        
    
}


親フォルダー ID が正しく指定されてない可能性があると思い、私の回答に「親フォルダー ID の確認」の項目を追記したので、こちら確認いただければと思います。

Google Drive の設定の問題かどうかの切り分けとして、OAuth 認証しているユーザーで、ブラウザーからログインして、UI 操作で、共有フォルダー以下にフォルダーを作成できるか確認ください。ただしくフォルダーが作成できるのであれば、API 経由でも同一共有フォルダー以下にフォルダーは作成できるはずです。

追記ありがとうございます。追記された内容を見ると、共有フォルダーではなく、「共有ドライブ」の特定フォルダー以下に、フォルダーを作成したいということですね？私は、ユーザー ドライブの特定フォルダーを他のユーザーに権限を付与して共有フォルダーにし、同フォルダー以下にフォルダーを作成したいのだと勘違いしておりました。ついては、フォルダー作成時の要求先を「POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true」に変更。要求本文の JSON に、「"driveId": "共有ドライブの ID"  」を追加して試してみてください。

コメントだと、要求先が正しく表示されなかったので、私の回答に「共有ドライブを対象とする場合」を追記しました。

解決に至った情報は質問に直接追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。(質問はあくまで "質問" の体裁を保つべきです)

解決してよかったです。もし、私の回答で解決に至ったのであれば、私の回答を承認いただけければと思います。また、上記コメントにもあるように、最後の解決部分は、切り離し、個別の回答とて投稿するのが良いと思います。

cubick様、hiromasa masuda様
ありがとうございます。
最後の書き込みは分離して、「質問に回答する」で回答する様に致しました。

私が試したところ、以下の内容で、問題なく共有フォルダー以下に、新規フォルダーを作成することができました。
フォルダー作成に使用した API
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

API での要求本文
{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "name": "フォルダー名",
    "parents": [ "親共有フォルダーの ID"]
}

要求本文に多くのプロパティを設定しているようですが、上記 4 つのプロパティで、フォルダーを作成できました。要求本文が、正しいフォーマットにシリアライズされていることを確認、設定しているプロパティを最小限にして、問題を切り分けていただくと良いと思います。
親フォルダー ID の確認
確認事項として、親フォルダー ID が正しく設定されているでしょうか？
ブラウザーで、対象の親フォルダーを開き、URL 部分を確認することで、フォルダー ID を確認できます。
以下の画像で、黒く塗りつぶししてますが、赤四角で囲った部分が、フォルダー ID となります。

ブラウザーで確認したフォルダー ID が、エラーメッセージで表示されるフォルダー ID と一致しているかを確認ください。
エラーメッセージ内の親フォルダー ID は、以下 <親フォルダーID> 部分となります。
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "File not found: <親フォルダーID>.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "File not found: <親フォルダーID>.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "location": "fileId",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}

ブラウザーで確認したフォルダー ID とエラーメッセージで表示されるフォルダー ID が一致している場合は、共有フォルダーに API を実行したユーザーの権限が付与されおらず、API を実行したユーザーから共有フォルダーが参照できない、もしくは、API 要求時のエンコード等の処理でフォルダー ID が、別の ID に書き換わってしまっていることが考えられます。
共有ドライブを対象とする場合
共有ドライブを対象とする場合は、クエリパラメーター: supportsAllDrives=true を要求先に付与します。
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true

さらに、要求本文に driveId を追加し、対象とする共有ドライブの ID を設定します。
{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "name": "フォルダー名",
    "driveId": "<共有ドライブ ID>"
    "parents": [ "親共有フォルダーの ID"]
}

参考情報

API: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create?hl=ja
要求本文: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files?hl=ja#File
共有ドライブのサポート: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-shareddrives?hl=ja


hiromasa masuda様
ご回答を頂き大変ありがとうございます。
ご指導に従い修正しましたが、エラーになります。
細かい事情を記載するには「質問に回答する」で
宜しいでしょうか？

追加情報であれば、ご自身の質問を編集し追記いただければと思います。
私の回答に対してのことであれば、このコメント欄でお伝えいただければと思います。

「共有フォルダー」という不正確な用語でミスリードしてしまい大変失礼致しました。
フォルダー作成時の要求先を POST googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supports AllDrives=true に変更。
要求本文の JSON に「"driveId": "共有ドライブの ID" 」を追加して試してみてくださいというご指導に従い、
endPoint2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true"; とし、
postParmMap.put("driveId", DRIVE_ID ); と共有ドライブのIDをセットした所、上手く動きました。
以下にソースを添付します。
String endPoint2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true";
System.out.println( "endPoint2="  +  endPoint2 );
// POSTデータの生成
HttpResponse<String>        response        =    null;
String                      responseBody    =    "";
List<String>tempParentFolderID;
tempParentFolderID    =    new ArrayList<String>();
tempParentFolderID.add(parentFolderID);

Map<String, Object> postParmMap = new HashMap<>();
postParmMap.put("kind", "drive#file" );                                    //Kind
postParmMap.put("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" );        //mimeType
postParmMap.put("name", targetFolderName);                                 //フォルダー名
postParmMap.put("driveId", DRIVE_ID );                                     //共有ドライブのID
postParmMap.put("parents",tempParentFolderID);                             //親フォルダーID
System.out.println( "postParmMap=" + new Gson().toJson(postParmMap) );

今回、参ったのは supportsAllDrives=true です。
このパラメータを postParmMap.put("supportsAllDrives", true); とPostの
パラメータに設定していましたが、
https://www.googleapis.(略)v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true とURLの
末尾に追加しないといけなかったのですね。
フォルダーのリネームも同様でした。


親共有フォルダーのIDの最後に「.」が付いていますが、これは問題無いので
しょうか？

存在しない親フォルダID('parents'=['@@@@'])を指定して、フォルダ作成を試みたところ以下のエラーを取得しました。
フォルダーIDの最後に「.」を付けてエラーメッセージが表示されているようです。
問題ないのではないでしょうか。
[{
    'message': 'File not found: @@@@.',
    'domain': 'global',
    'reason': 'notFound',
    'location': 'fileId',
    'locationType': 'parameter'
}]

お試しで、共有ドライブID(事前に取得)を指定して、ルート直下にフォルダを作成してみてはいかがでしょうか。
